# Javascript ComputedStyle: getPropertyValue() is way slow in IE. Is there a fix?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

My javascript runs through the DOM of a webpage and, for each node, gets the computed style:

```
var computedStyle =  window.getComputedStyle(element);
```

It then uses this to get about 20 values, for example:

```
c_style = computedStyle.getPropertyValue("height");
```

This is proving to be WAY slow in IE (tried IE11 and IE9).

If I just get the getComputedStyle style then the time for the page is 0.3 seconds (the script also does other things).

If I add in the getPropertyValue, the time for the page increases to 3 full seconds. However, in Firefox, it makes virtually no difference that the script is also looking up these values.

Is there another way to do it in IE (9+)? Or is something else going wrong?

**EDIT: Have others had success (= good performance) getting a lot of styles out of IE?**

Comment: What other things? Do you change styling of the page in between, so that each `get` triggers a reflow?

Comment: I don't make any changes to the html or styling. I just loop through, collect information (text, styles, etc.), and stick the info into lists.

Comment: Whether or not there is "another way" this sounds like a pretty classic memory for time tradeoff made by the non-IE browser developers. "Computed" styles are artifacts of the layout engine, which is outside the JavaScript engine and the DOM -- quicker lookups by cacheing layout engine data at DOM nodes. In browsers using this tradeoff `getComputedStyle()` might execute more quickly, but more memory is allocated for each DOM element and likely garbage collection becomes more complicated. The IE devs probably just haven't decided to invest the resources to refactor their engine this way (yet?).